# Determine if file is a system file or not, as well as owner of the file using php

Tags: php

I am trying to identify a way how to determine if a file is a system file or not using php. I also want to find out owner of the file and owner's domain.

I have tried different ways to determine if file is system file or not, 
i.e. `is_file()`, `fileperms()`. 
Next I am planning to build function around file name which returns true if file has extensions like `.ini`, `.db`, `.tmp` etc or the file name starts with "`". Let me know if someone has better idea to do this.

Also, I am trying to find out owner of the file and owner's domain like `"NTRSK\USER1"`, For this I tried

```
$stat = stat($file);
// returns 0 always   

echo(posix_getpwuid($stat['uid']));
// got fatal error 'undefined function posix_getpwuid()'
```

I also tired `fileowner($file);// returned 0`, I want something like `"NTRSK\USER1"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use command line execution if you're on Linux

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lh'); <-- for an example
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";      <-- use the output value to determine file status or owner depending on which command you're using. 
?>
```

Comment: I am running it on Windows machine. I know on windows machine, we can get it by following,                                   var f = fso.GetFolder(searchFolder);
//get list of files from the folder
var fc = new Enumerator(f.Files);                             Var fileAttributes = fc.item().attributes; I am running my script on xampp server and accessing file system on windows machine. I have local set up of this.